# Изучение литературы на английском

Tags: книги

Нарабатываю стек по .Net, и очевидно, что большинство актуальной литературы будет в русском переводе только через год-два. Уровень английского pre-intermediate - intermediate с натяжкой, то есть общую суть прочитанного улавливаю, но за многими словами приходится лезть в словарь (а в тех.литературе каждое слово несет какую-то смысловую нагрузку).
Как лучше поступить в данной ситуации? Читать предыдущие издания книг, русские локализации которых уже есть, или потно и медленно читать на английском? Я понимаю, что английский для программиста must have, но сейчас как-то больше нацеленность на технологии и скорейшее трудоустройство (студент).

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги по C# и другая литература](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416584/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be-c-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0)

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416584/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-c-%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0  может подойдет?

Comment: Со списком литературы я знаком, я же сказал, что последние издания книг актуальных - на английском. Вот я и задался вопросом: изучать книги по последним русским изданиям или же не заморачиваться по поводу некоторых пробелов в осмыслении текста на английском.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы порекомендовал не лезть в дебри дотнета ещё и если английский хромает, а попробовать обучиться чему-то попроще и подокументированнее - и с навыками чего с трудоустройством проблем не будет. Например PHP - серверная разработка, JS - клиентская разработка, Delphi - настольные приложения. Дотнет весьма сложен даже с чтением документации даже опытным программистам, сложно писать правильно на нём - я бы не стал с него начинать путь работы программистом)

Comment: Кто сказал, что я его начинаю? Я лишь приступил к углубленному изучению, для которого мне и требуется экскурс в более актуальную литературу на английском. В любом случае спасибо.

Comment: Незачто. Если ты студент и ищешь работу - вероятнее всего начинаешь. Те кто его знают и изучают углублённо: работу не ищут :)

Comment: Просто я только сейчас решил, что у меня достаточно знания чтобы пробоваться куда-то на traynee или джуна, но для большей уверенности, пока лето, решил закрепить свои знания.